# Updating a local repository with changes from a GitHub repository

Tags: git, github

I've got a project checked locally from GitHub, and that remote repository has since had changes made to it. What's the correct command to update my local copy with the latest changes?

Comment: Its worth noting that github have produced a set of very informative and helpful guides for using git and github. I found them invaluable when I first made the move to git. https://help.github.com/

Answer (score 1081, accepted):

Probably:

```
either:    git pull origin master

    or:    git pull origin main
```

Comment: It complained:  
"You asked to pull from the remote 'origin', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line."  
So I tried  "$ git pull origin master" and it worked fine.

Comment: git pull origin master

Comment: I deleted some files and it is not bringing them again, any idea?

Comment: do we do a git commit before running this? everytime i run this command, i end up with 18347213846 modified files that i didnT even touch!!!

Comment: I just learned the hard way that pulling a new remote repository branch does not create a branch of that name locally, but instead pulls that remote branch into whatever local branch happens to be checked out. I'm not sure how to undo this short of ditching and re-cloning the repository. In any case, it seems that the local branch is independent of the remote branch and one should always make sure you're in the intended local branch before pulling.

Comment: Why we want to do merge ,but I think fetch is OK .What if code is diseased or not healthy contribution? Is git pull  one is safe command?

Comment: If I made changes lokally but don't want them be merged, just get the exact copy of the remote repo, then I have to delete or rename my lokal repo and just clone it again, right?

Comment: @JuanLanus why additional origin master required?  won't git pull will be sufficient?

Comment: @Ankush: for most of us there is no need to name a branch because we work on a single branch "master", but multi-developer teams usually work in many branches at once, thus the requirement to identify it.
For Git, the "master" name is not special, is just another branch name.

Comment: franc  I always try to remember to take a full copy of my current local directory, because I don't know git arcana well enough to undo anything strange - like Joe Lapp's problem above

Comment: `git remote -vv`  and  `git branch -vv`  might help you understand what's going on too:  first one gives you the details of the 'remote' repository - the repository on the server, not your local/working repository:  second one gives you the details of the branch from your local repository you have checked out, and the details of the corresponding branch from the remote repository .

Comment: 2021 update: `git pull origin main`

Many repos are moving away from master - and Github repo's default is now `main`

Answer (score 141):

This should work for every default repo:

```
git pull origin master
```

If your default branch is different than `master`, you will need to specify the branch name:

```
git pull origin my_default_branch_name
```

Comment: Not really. 

fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master

Comment: @Eijkhout probablt in Your repo case there is no master branch, and some other branch is set as default

Answer (score 78):

```
git fetch [remotename]
```

However you'll need to merge any changes into your local branches. If you're on a branch that's tracking a remote branch on Github, then

```
git pull
```

will first do a fetch, and then merge in the tracked branch

Comment: If you are using the `git fetch` method, you'll also want to fetch tags with `git fetch -t`.  If you're satisfied with the changes (`git log HEAD..FETCH_HEAD`), you can then merge them in with `git merge FETCH_HEAD`.

Answer (score 27):

This question is very general and there are a couple of assumptions I'll make to simplify it a bit. We'll assume that you want to update your `master` branch.

If you haven't made any changes locally, you can use `git pull` to bring down any new commits and add them to your `master`.

```
git pull origin master
```

If you have made changes, and you want to avoid adding a new merge commit, use `git pull --rebase`.

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

`git pull --rebase` will work even if you haven't made changes and is probably your best call.

Comment: Rebase, and the dangers of rebase:  https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase.   Paragraphs 2 and 3 of the "Understanding the dangers of rebase"  really make me miss SVN's command set.

Answer (score 17):

With an already-set origin master, you just have to use the below command -

```
git pull "https://github.com/yourUserName/yourRepo.git"
```

Answer (score 12):

### Complete Workflow for check out a branch and pull changes from master

**Pull all remote branches**

> git pull --all

**List all branches now**

> git branch -a

**Download your branch**

> git checkout -b `<feature branch name copied from list of branches above>`

**Shows current branch.  Must show `<feature branch>` with * In front of it**

> git branch

**Checkout changes from master to current branch**

> git pull origin master

**OR checkout any other `<feature branch>` into current branch**

> git pull origin  `<feature-branch>`

Answer (score 7):

To pull from the default branch, new repositories should use the command:

```
git pull origin main
```

Github changed naming convention of default branch from master to main in 2020. https://github.com/github/renaming

Comment: Regardless of GitHub's policy change, main might not be the GitHub default branch.  The user can specify a default branch name.

If  your goal is to pull from the GitHub default branch then there is no need to specify a branch...main, master, or otherwise.

"git pull" will act on the default remote and the default branch.

Answer (score 4):

`git pull origin master` // Change in github, it take effect in local reprository

NB: Working Fine

All about git: https://gist.github.com/subrotoice/b27f7d20617bb3da04827a223faf6450

```
Complete Documentation
googel>>Install Git
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git // Type "git" to check it work or not?

#Basic Windows command like cd
cd\  = back to root directory c drive does not metter where its current postion 
cd .. = One step back
cd /d D: = C Drive to D drive
dir or ls(LS)  = List all file and folder of current directory. "ls" is more clear to read
mkdir mynewfolder = Create New Folder
cd "folderName" = To enter Folder for doing some task
cls = Clear Screen

#Upload A full new project (Make sure no file there even readme.md to avoid error)--Working==========
git config --global user.name "subrotoice"
git config --global user.email "subroto.iu@gmail.com"

git init    // Basically 3 steps, 1. add, 2. Commit, 3. Push
git add .   // Add to local repositories
git commit -m "first commit"  // Commit to local repositories
git remote add origin https://github.com/subrotoice/ccn.git  // ("origin user-defined", origin=url.git, variable e value assign korar moto)
git push -u origin master  // push,  origin user define name like variable contain url. (master default brunch name, you can create brunch like, https://prnt.sc/26pq9x2

#master(default),  If you want to create other brunch not master(default), here brunch name is "main", user-defined name
git branch -M main // Create new branch main
git remote add origin https://github.com/subrotoice/33sfdf.git  // origin(any name) is variable name contain url, age url assing thakle ei line dorkar nai
git push -u origin main

git branch // Show current branch
git checkout master // Switched to branch 'master'

#Work on existing Project----------------
First you have to download project otherwise it will not work
git clone https://github.com/Tilotiti/jQuery-LightBox-Responsive.git   // Pull
cd folder_name // Need to change to inside folder
git add . For all new file and folder (git add file_names.exten  it is for single file)
git status  // to check the status of git files [optional]
git commit -m "committed message" For asingle file(git commit -m "committed message" file_names.exten)
git push -u origin master
git pull origin master // Change in github, it take effect in local reprository. 'Synchronization'

# Clone a Specic Brunch, in stade of main brunch master
git clone --branch <branchname> <remote-repo-url>
git clone -b <branchname> <remote-repo-url>
git clone -b main9 https://github.com/subrotoice/test9.git  // Working, Here brunch name main9
git push -u origin main9 // Push to main9, Error: if use master as brunch name
git pull origin master // Change in github, it take effect in local reprository 

#VS Code--- Command dorkar nai, Sob visually kora jai
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2oihkInZ880  (Hindi)
1st time step: -----(Local: 1-3, Remote: a-d)--------------
1. Initialize Repository // https://prnt.sc/V7oDXeeOi9CO
2. Commit  // Visually Commit
3. COnfig Git(If ask)

a. Add Remote  // Visually Commit https://prnt.sc/-IWSFNeadc1H
b. Push  // Commit and push option ase vscode
c. Github Auth
d. Push Again (If required)

2nd Time (Old Project):
1. Pule (clone) // https://prnt.sc/K2us0_eYZFuq
2. Commit

a. Push
# https://prnt.sc/5ii9wCPT9Qut // Change in github, it take effect in local reprository
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this to update your local repo with the updated one in remote repo like Gitlab, Github, etc.

```
git pull origin master
```

Comment: This exact answer has already been provided multiple times. Please upvote existing answers instead of adding new answers, unless you have a new approach.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is determine **which branch** you need to pull from GitHub. Borrowing a graphic from the [Viewing branches in your repository document from GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/viewing-branches-in-your-repository), you can ***explore*** all the available branches by clicking the button that's contained in the red box shown in the graphic below. The label on the button might be `main`, it might be `master` - or it might be something else. If it's a relatively simple GitHub site, this button will likely be labeled `main` or `master`.

You can click on the *"branch button"* to expand the list of branches - or go to the bottom of the list and choose `View all branches`.

[image]

If you're still unsure, you can go into your local repository and find the name of your **current branch**. *Most likely* this will be the branch you should update from:

```bash
$ cd ./mylocalgitrepo 
$ git branch --show-current
master           # or main, or ...
# alternatively, to see all available branches:
$ git branch
...
```

Once you've discovered **which branch** (i.e. the `<branch-of-interest>`), the rest of the task is fairly trivial:

```bash
$ git pull origin <branch-of-interest>

# perhaps: 'git pull origin master', or 'git pull origin main', or ...
```

Answer (score 0):

After Git Clone, if want to get the remote branches use

```
git fetch --all
```

Then checkout to the branch you want

```
git checkout the-branch-you-need
```