# Github repo out of sync with local

Tags: git, github

I have a master project stored on my development machine. I push this to Github when changes are made.

But, I made 2 changes directly on Github as they were only modifications to the README and I was on a different computer.

My local is now different to the remote (the Github repo).

How do I get the local back in sync? The local was the main copy, but I think it's better to have the Github repo as the master.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating a local repository with changes from a Github repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443210/updating-a-local-repository-with-changes-from-a-github-repository)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run a `git pull origin main` and merge with your local.

When done merging do `git push origin main` to sync up the remote

If your local changes are too large you can use `git stash` to hide them temporarily and pop them out of the stash (`git stash pop`).

---

EDIT: October 2020: Github changed `master` to `main`. For older git repos please use `master` instead of `main` in above commands

Comment: Thanks. The pull worked perfectly. Why do I have to push back to origin if I've just pulled from it?

Comment: To send your local changes back. (assuming you had some)

Comment: Ah, I see. I hadn't made any yet, but that makes sense.

Comment: Just a note. Github has changed the default branch name from `master` to `main` in 2020.

Comment: Updated to reflect that