# do I run "git pull" in the same directory as I first did "git clone"

Tags: git

Sorry. I'm still confused after reading the git docs.
I first did:

```
$[home/myname]git clone git@bitbucket.org/.../nlp.git
```

It created 'nlp' directory under home/myname. Then I wrote lots of code under

```
$[/home/myname/nlp/.../myapp/]
```

Now I need to pull the latest nlp. Do I do it under my home directory as

```
$[home/myname]git pull git@bitbucket.org/.../nlp.git
```

Will it affect the codes I wrote in 'myapp'?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: you need to cd into the cloned directory, in your case `nlp` or `nlp.git`, and then run any git commands in there. git clone is the only exception that needs to be done from the parent directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating a local repository with changes from a Github repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443210/updating-a-local-repository-with-changes-from-a-github-repository)

Comment: @Joe:  I'm not seeing that as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks! Will the code I wrote in 'myapp'  be affected by doing 'git pull'. I want to make sure they won't disappear or be merged.

Answer (score 1):

You run `git pull` in the same directory as your repository, so in this case, it would mean running it in your `nlp` directory.  If you attempted to do it in a non-Git directory, you would get a helpful error message:

> ```
> fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home/<user>)
> Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
> ```

Attempting to pull new code from upstream *can* impact your code if you're working directly on a branch which has new code on it.  To mitigate this issue, it's advised to create a local branch for yourself, then pull down the latest copy from master, *then* merge that master branch into your local branch and deal with any conflicts.

Comment: As hinted at in the error message here, you can also run `git pull` from a *subdirectory* of `nlp`, such as `/home/myname/nlp/.../myapp/`

Comment: @8bittree:  You're absolutely right, but my preference is to be in the top directory since I usually do `git pull` and `git add .` like it's second nature, and `git add .` won't work if you're in a subdirectory with no changes.

Comment: True, but I figured it might be helpful for people to know that it's an option.