# Git sync with GitHub repository

Tags: windows, git, github, synchronization, command

I have a desktop PC and a laptop, I use both daily to commit to the same repository on GitHub (via Git). I have just moved over and started using Git, which is great. However, what command do I use when, for example, I have made changes on my desktop PC and committed them to GitHub, and then I want to move all of the changes currently on GitHub onto my laptop files to resume my work on my laptop where I left off on my desktop PC / GitHub?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: googling this sort of stuff would be quicker for an answer but i think what you're looking for is `git pull` on the laptop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating a local repository with changes from a Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443210/updating-a-local-repository-with-changes-from-a-github-repository)

Answer (score 2):

Clone a repository into a new directory ;

```
git clone uri_repository.git
```

Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch.

```
git pull
```

Show the working tree status.

```
git status
```

Update the index using the current content found in the working tree.

```
git add .
```

Record changes to the repository.

```
git commit -m 'message'
```

Update remote references (refs) along with associated objects.

```
git push
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to syn your remote repository to your local repository

```
/* origin points to your remote repository, master is the branch in which your working */ 

git pull origin master
```

Incase you dont have remote ie origin setup then

```
/* Here your aliasing your remote repository location to origin, you can name it anything */

git remote add origin your_git_repo_url
```

In case if you dont know which branch your currently working then

```
/* This will list all the branches with * preceded which is active one */

git branch
```

Once you do your local changes then you may want to push the code to remote repository which can be done as follows

```
git add .

   OR 

git add file1.txt file2.txt

git commit -m "You commit description"

git push origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

To fetch your code from your remote repository from GitHub you use the command `git pull`. This fetches the latest changes and merges them with your local code so you have the most recent code. You can find a Git cheat sheet with most of the commands you will need [here](https://services.github.com/on-demand/resources/cheatsheets/)