# Github : how to merge code from github to local

Tags: git, github

I have some updated code in the GitHub master I don't have that updates. But I too have some Updates in my branch(which are not present in master). Now I want to download new updated code that present in master to my branch `editinfo`  but I don't want to it to erase my code(my updates). I want my changes to be also present.How can I do it, Can someone help me with commands?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating a local repository with changes from a Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443210/updating-a-local-repository-with-changes-from-a-github-repository)

Answer (score 0):

Just pull the remote changes to your `master` branch and merge with your `editinfo` branch.

A simple `git pull` should update your current master. See [the documentation on how to merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) your `editinfo` branch.

If the answer doesnt fit, please be more specific.