# how to update android studio project from github

Tags: android, github

I'm working on a project on GitHub, the developer updated the version on GitHub. How can I get the latest version on my Android Studio without deleting the old version?

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you want to get any help

Comment: open command line, type "git pull"

Comment: Do you have git enable in Android Studio ? If not you will need to install and enable the plugin for git integration within the IDE. Otherwise you can use commands to update the project from terminal. See this question for commands  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443210/updating-a-local-repository-with-changes-from-a-github-repository

Comment: I get this : 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external comand .

Comment: did you download the project as a zip file?

Comment: yes I download the project as a zip