# How to compare and update local repo with remote Github repo?

Tags: git, github, git-diff

I was wondering if there are any API's or tricks to find out if my program (visual basic) is different from the one on my repositories master branch.

Also, if it is not, how would I go about updating mine from the new one in the master branch?

Comment: See [How to compare a local git branch with its remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800783/how-to-compare-a-local-git-branch-with-its-remote-branch) and [Updating a local repository with changes from a Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1443210/2745495).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're unsure your local project is updated use this command:

```
git pull origin master
```

To see differences between your local and remote projects use this:

```
git diff <local branch> <remote>/<remote branch>
```

You can find more [on git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

Comment: It might be better to do a `git fetch` first to see the changes first. Then do a `git pull` to update the local copy.

Answer (score 0):

`git diff` is the git tool to let you see changes between commits, branches, and the like. `git pull` is the git tool to fetch a repository and merge the latest changes.

These tools should have manpages under `git-diff(1)` and `git-pull(1)` respectively.