# Clone An Updated Repository?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-branch, github-pages

I have clone a Repository called **MyRepo** Contains (a,b,c,d) files and It's updated with  (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)files. Now how do i Clone **Updated Repository** (I'm just **removing old repo**. and **reinstalling** the **updated repo**. Is there **any option** to **clone updates** **without deleting total repo?**)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating a local repository with changes from a Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443210/updating-a-local-repository-with-changes-from-a-github-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+update+local+repository

Answer (score 2):

Cloning is something you usually do only once. Since you already cloned your repo, a way to update your files locally with changes introduced in the origin (server) is to use `git pull`.

I recommend reading at least about git basics here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2  This book is really well-written, available for free and in many different languages.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying that you have cloned your remote git repo to your local system and updated local system repo and want to add this to remote again right.

so, you can push your updated local repo on remote git repo. you just have to git add . and commit and push.

Comment: No I just want to install updates from From the Repo . . I'm not changing anything I'm trying to install changed/updated Repository.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command 'git pull' from an already cloned repo to get updates

You can take a look at [gitexplorer.com](https://gitexplorer.com), it's a web app that helps with git commands

Answer (score 0):

So you have cloned a repository and updated the original afterwards.

To update your **cloned** repository you can add it as a remote to your updated **origin** repository by using `git remote add nameOfRemote "pathofclonedrepo"`. If this works you can update the remote via `git push nameOfRemote master` or `git push nameOfRemote HEAD`.

If you really want to clone your repo **again** (not recommended) without deleting the old clone, you only have to repeat `clone` with a new path.