# Pull changes from remote Git repository and commit my branch to the remote repo

Tags: git, github

my use case is. I have made changes to my local repo with a branch called feature A. The remote repo is called origin. There have been changes made to origin/master. I need to sync with origin master and push my changes(feature A) to the remote repo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443210/updating-a-local-repository-with-changes-from-a-github-repository

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+update+local+repository

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/how-do-i-push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-track-it-too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+remote+repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to use `git fetch` to load data from your remote repository.
Then you can use `git rebase origin/master` to move your local changes on top of origin/master, on your local repository.

Now using `git push` you will push your branch `feature A` on the remote repository.
If you prefer to push on master, you will have to use the following syntax :`git push origin master`