# Updating local folder with new contents from a git repo

Tags: github, git-bash

I cloned a git repo into my pc using this command in my git bash

```
git clone https://github.com/xxx/yyy.git
```

which created a folder called yyy in my pc.

How can I update the folder yyy in my pc with new contents of the https://github.com/xxx/yyy.git (is it called remote repo)?

I followed the instructions in [Updating a local repository with changes from a Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443210/updating-a-local-repository-with-changes-from-a-github-repository), in particular `git pull origin master` but none of them worked and returned the error `$ git pull origin master
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`.

I also tried `git pull https://github.com/xxx/yyy.git` as I reasoned that if I successfully did `git clone https://github.com/xxx/yyy.git`, the `git pull https://github.com/xxx/yyy.git` must work otherwise git syntax is not great.

Should I do the "clone" again to overwrite the existing folder in my pc? Why can't I do "pull"?

Comment: What is the error with `git pull`?

Comment: Hi Anurag. I've just updated the question with error message.

Answer (score 14):

You need to issue git commands from within the cloned repository:

```
cd yyy
git pull
```

Comment: can we do this without cd ?

Comment: Yes. Since git 1.8.5 you can do `git -C yyy pull` from the directory you were in when you performed the clone

Comment: and i think that should be the best answer ?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably executing this command from outside the yyy folder. You have to go into it first:

```
cd yyy
git pull
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I did change the default directory of git bash to the folder zzz where it contains yyy because that what I did (cd zzz) when I did ```git clone ....```. It WORKS! Thankyou. But why do I have to change it to yyy instead of zzz?

Comment: Because you can clone multiple git repo's. If it would work from outside the folder, git would have no way to know which repo to pull in.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you meant by multiple git repo's? Do you mean another repo like  https://github.com/aaa/bbb.git? or  https://github.com/xxx/yyy.git?

Comment: Yes, cloning both would result in 2 folders (bbb and yyy). You can then choose which folder to work in by going into the folder with `cd bbb` or `cd yyy`. From there you need to execute all your git commands like `git pull`, `git commit`, ...

Comment: Thankyou, Sam. Would you mind looking at this error I've just got it now when doing git pull ```Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
Updating 5deedcc..9e2c1b4```. Is my local folder updated? How can I commit?

Comment: It looks like you made changes to your folder. You can `git add .` to track all changes you just made and then `git commit -m "a message"` to commit those changes. You can also `git status` to see which files you have changed.