# Updating a specific cloned branch on local machine

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-pull, git-fetch

I have cloned just a specific git branch to my local machine. How do I incorporate the changes made in that branch to reflect in my local machine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+update+local+repository

Answer (score 0):

After cloning the repository, you can simply use

```
git pull remotename branchname
```

In order to incorporate the changes, you can also use `git fetch` and `git merge`, but `git pull` is a shortcut for both of them

To get a detailed explaination you can refer this [official documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/getting-changes-from-a-remote-repository) and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443210/updating-a-local-repository-with-changes-from-a-github-repository)