# Do you constantly need to clone the repositories on github when someone uploads/makes a change?

Tags: git, github

I am confused about how it works,

I'm new to git hub, I was just wondering when someone makes a change, how will it go about updating it, etc. Do I have to clone after every change?

Comment: No. You need to read the documentation or perhaps some high-level guides and check the `git pull` command https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

Comment: https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/

Comment: The following thread has answers to your question: [Updating a local repository with changes from a GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443210/updating-a-local-repository-with-changes-from-a-github-repository)

Comment: I think you need to learn some of the basics of git:
https://learngitbranching.js.org/

Answer (score 1):

you can :

```
git pull
```

inside the folder to get the updates